# windows authentication in iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

I am using IIS7 Windows 7 Enterprise. I need to set up windows authentication, but it is not available in IIS7.

How do I get windows authentication in IIS7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Control Panel** => **Programs** =>  **Turn Windows features on or off**

[image]

Once done click Ok, go to your IIS Manager, and there you should be able to see Windows Authentication in the options.

Answer (score 1):

To configure Windows authentication

You can perform this procedure by using the user interface (UI), by running Appcmd.exe commands in a command-line window, by editing configuration files directly, or by writing WMI scripts.

User Interface
To use the UI

1- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

2- In Features View, double-click Authentication.

3- On the Authentication page, select Windows Authentication.

4- In the Actions pane, click Enable to use Windows authentication.

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(WS.10).aspx